# Polymer 2.0 - Uncaught TypeError: this._propertySetter is not a function

Tags: polymer-2.x

I am trying to build my personal website using Polymer 2.0.0-rc.7 and WebComponents 1.0.0-rc.5.

But my custom elements are not showing up on the Chrome browser (Version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)) and IE 11, I have opened the DevTools and saw the below errors.

Please help me if you know the solution for the below errors.

Thanks.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._propertySetter is not a function
at HTMLElement.__setMulti (app-route.html:402)
at HTMLElement.__tryToMatch (app-route.html:328)
at Object.runMethodEffect [as fn] (property-effects.html:768)
at runEffectsForProperty (property-effects.html:137)
at runEffects (property-effects.html:103)
at HTMLElement._propertiesChanged (property-effects.html:1554)
at HTMLElement._flushProperties (property-accessors.html:496)
at HTMLElement._flushClients (property-effects.html:1468)
at HTMLElement._propertiesChanged (property-effects.html:1550)
at HTMLElement._flushProperties (property-accessors.html:496)


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
app-scroll-effects-behavior.html:274
at HTMLElement._effectsChanged (app-scroll-effects-behavior.html:274)
at Object.runMethodEffect [as fn] (property-effects.html:768)
at runEffectsForProperty (property-effects.html:137)
at runEffects (property-effects.html:103)
at HTMLElement._propertiesChanged (property-effects.html:1554)
at HTMLElement._flushProperties (property-accessors.html:496)
at HTMLElement._invalidateProperties (property-effects.html:1432)
at HTMLElement._setProperty (property-effects.html:1418)
at HTMLElement.Object.defineProperty.set (property-accessors.html:391)
at HTMLElement.connectedCallback (legacy-element-mixin.html:82)
```

Comment: I guess way more context is needed as this is a pretty generic error... probably some problems with elements you are using?